# Searching dates using ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, query, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to understand how dates are queried in the ArcGIS Server REST API (v10) using the query functionality (`...MapServer/find?searchText=...`). If I search on a string attribute I can get a result and its date field shows the value "6/1/1995". However if I then search by the date field using "6/1/1995" I get 0 results.

Am I supposed to provide my date in a particular format? I tried reversing the date's components' ordering, changing the separator, with/without leading zeros, and even tried the timestamp to no avail. I'm not in control of the service or the data so I don't know if any settings are in place in the source data that make this more difficult. The field's format is reported as `esriFieldTypeDate` with length 36.

[Understanding Date Time Format output in ArcGIS REST API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/72943) suggests I should be seeing the date field reported as a timestamp in the JSON output of my query but in both HTML and JSON it is "6/1/1995".

I saw [this thread on the ArcGIS forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/20426-Did-the-date-format-change-for-Query-REST-Post-JSON-responses-at-ags-10) but as using a timestamp didn't help me I assume it's not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 10.0 (and I believe 10.1 also), you can query dates using the syntax of the underlying database -- for example, in Oracle you can use "TO_DATE('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"

See documentation here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/

This has changed in 10.2 where ArcGIS Server is set to use standardized queries by default, so you will need to use the format "date 'yyyy-mm-dd'":
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//015400000686000000

Comment: OK thanks for the info. I'm glad things have changed for 10.2 as expecting a service client to know the underlying architecture is ridiculous (and very 'ESRI')