# How can you search dates using the ArcGIS REST API's find tool

Tags: arcgis-server, query, arcgis-rest-api

Basically, I am trying to use a date as the searchText (e.g. `...MapServer/find?searchText=2023-10-19...), however it is not returning any results. The searchField I am using is a date time field, so when I input a date like 2023-10-19, I want to retrieve all the results whose value is within that day, regardless of the specific hour and minute, etc. (e.g. 2023-10-19 00:00:00, 2023-10-19 12:15:23)

[Searching dates using ArcGIS REST API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86805/searching-dates-using-arcgis-rest-api) seems related, but I tried the suggestions, and they didn't work.

Comment: what is the rest url (there have been changes in recent versions of ArcGIS online REST).

Comment: I think that you need more parameters in the search: ex. ...MapServer/find?searchText=2023-10-19&contains=true&searchFields=DateField&sr=&layers=ALL&layerDefs=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&dynamicLayers=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnUnformattedValues=false&returnFieldName=false&datumTransformations=&layerParameterValues=&mapRangeValues=&layerRangeValues=&clipping=&spatialFilter=&f=html